# AD Connect Login with public domain

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

In the office we sign in with user@corp.company.com or COMPANY\user

I have setup AD Connect and it is syncing users correctly and mapping them to user@company.onmicrosoft.com

I have registered company.com and it is set up correctly in the Admin center

How do I ensure that users are mapped correctly to user@company.com for email and signin?

Comment: If you can't find an answer here, you may also try it at superuser: https://superuser.com/

Comment: We can check sync rules and sync tasks to ensure that users are mapped correctly,

Answer (score 0):

> How do I ensure that users are mapped correctly to user@company.com
>   for email and signin?

Do you mean you want to add AD suffixes company.com, and change all your AD accounts use company.com UPN?

When we add domain name to Azure AD, for example, we add company.com, all on-prem user sync to Azure AD, will map to use1@company.onmicrosoft.com.(Use **default rules**)

If your on-prem AD accounts have user1@conmany.com and user1@crop.company.com, then use AAD connect to sync to Azure AD, we will find two users accounts, one is user1@company.onmicrosoft.com, another is user11234@company.onmicrosoft.com.

So if we want to ensure that users are mapped correctly, we can check **AAD connect sync rules**, make sure the rules configure correct. Then open synchronization service, check the **sync tasks** running correctly.

Comment: Does this helpful? Please let me know if you would like further assistance.